# Functional programming pattern for tabulation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I find myself using a pattern like this quite a lot:

```
const objectArray = [
  { name: "Bob", value: 20 },
  { name: "Jane", value: 15 },
  { name: "John", value: 5 },
  { name: "Jane", value: 10 },
];

objectArray.reduce((result, nextValue) => {
  if (!(nextValue.name in result)) result[nextValue.name] = 0;
  result[nextValue.name] += nextValue.value;
  return result;
}, {}); // { Bob: 20, Jane: 25, John: 5 }
```

I.e. I reduce an array of object into a dictionary of key-value pairs, using some keys and values from the objects & a reduce function (`+` in the example above but could be anything). Importantly, if a key doesn't yet exist, it has to get initialized with some value.

I was wondering, anyone know of some elegant way to make it more functional, i.e. abstract away the imperative `if` statement for checking whether the key exists & the mutating statement, all the while still keeping it usable within `Array.prototype.reduce()`.

Comment: If you mean just make it one line you can just use nullish coallescing, but it doesn't make it more 'functional' `const result = objectArray.reduce((result, nextValue) => ((result[nextValue.name] = result[nextValue.name] ?? 0 + nextValue.value),result),{});` To make it more functional you would abstract the grouping logic to a generic state that accepted parameters that encapsulated the details.

Comment: No. Other languages [have data structures that solve this problem](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) or [solve it with a missing default property procedure](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.1/Hash.html#method-i-default_proc-3D) but there's no "better" solution in JS. You could use a [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) to intercept object property accesses and return the 0, but I wouldn't recommend it: the added complexity (and Proxies **cannot** be polyfilled) just isn't worth it.

Comment: Can you go into a little more detail about what form you think that abstraction should take. No matter how you approach this you'll still need to check for the existence of a property key, and you'll still need to do some addition. Instead of an `if` statement you might, for example use a [nullish coalescing assignment (`??=`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_assignment): `result[name] ??= 0`.

Comment: Thank you all, what you say makes a lot of sense. I've thought about it a bit more, and I think the issue is there's 4 pieces to the puzzle: to do the tabulation, I need 1) the key prop, 2) the value prop, 3) the reduce function, and 4) the (inner) initial value. That doesn't really play well with `Array.prototype.reduce()`, because in that I can only specify the outer initial value (object) and the reduce function, so that's not enough. I'm probably better off writing a separate function for it rather than using `Array.prototype.reduce()`.

Comment: Btw I should mention, the ultimate goal is to be able to write the tabulation point-free.

Comment: If you don't mind an extra iteration of the data, you could seed your `reduce` with an empty table: `Object.fromEntries(objectArray.map(o => [ o.name, 0 ]))`. This lets you define the default argument (`0`), meaning you can skip the `in` check and just do `(acc, { name, value }) => { acc[name] += value; return acc; }` in your reducer

Answer (score 1):

```js
const objectArray = [
  { name: "Bob", value: 20 },
  { name: "John", value: 25 },
  { name: "Jane", value: 15 },
  { name: "John", value: 5 },
  { name: "Jane", value: 10 },
];

const res=objectArray.reduce((a,c)=>((a[c.name]=(a[c.name]??0)+c.value),a),{})

console.log(res)
```

Thanks, @Andy for the helpful comment! I thought my code was "self-explanatory". Apparently not, so let me add a few explanations:

- the expression `(a[c.name]??0)` will return the current value of `a[c.name]` or `0` if it does not yet exist
- `c.value` is then added to that value and stored again in `a[c.name]`
- and eventually, the last value (`a`) of a comma-separated list
  `((a[c.name]=(a[c.name]??0)+c.value), a)` is returned in the one-line callback function of the `Array.reduce()` function.

Comment: A barely-readable one-liner without any explanation might cover it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` with object destructuring and spread operator `...` like that:

```js
const objectArray = [
  { name: "Bob", value: 20 },
  { name: "Jane", value: 15 },
  { name: "John", value: 5 },
  { name: "Jane", value: 10 },
];

const result = objectArray.reduce((acc, { name, value }) => ({
  ...acc,
  [name]: (acc[name] || 0) + value,
}), {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Not the DV but this doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: don't use spread in reduce, it just increases the time and space complexity of the operation.

Comment: @pilchard, thanks for the tip. I use spread with reduce very often .  In case of simple data, the performance impact is negligible anyway.

Comment: Then keep writing it that way, but it doesn't save you any characters and is just plain inefficient. `(acc[name] = (acc[name] || 0) + value, acc)` identical length no unneccesary object creation, no iteration over the entire built object.

Comment: That's a better argument ;)

Comment: It's the only reason I could think that you would use it.